# Is there a "greater than but less than" function in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, search

I have an array:

```
times = [2, 5, 7.5, 8.5, 9, 10, 11.5, 13.5, 14.5, 17, 18, 19, 24]
```

I want a user to enter a time, say "11", and return "11.5" (`times.index(6)`) because it's greater than `10` but less than `11.5`.

Is there a way to do that in Ruby?

Comment: You're not explaining how the code should know that 11.5 is the correct solution. If someone entered `5` is `7.5` correct or should it be `nil` because nothing is withing a .5?

Comment: Welcome to SO! We'd like more detail. See "[ask]" and its linked pages.

Comment: @SEB : Also show your own attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: Your question could be re-opened if you clarify it (by editing).

Answer (score 3):

My answer suggests approaches that are efficient when `times` is large.

If, as in the question, `times` is sorted, we may want to perform a binary search:

```
times = [2, 5, 7.5, 8.5, 9, 10, 11.5, 13.5, 14.5, 17, 18, 19, 24]

times.bsearch { |x| x >= 11 }
  #=> 11.5
```

`nil` is returned if `times.max < 11`.

See [Array#bsearch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch).

Now suppose `times` is not sorted:

```
times.shuffle!
  #=> [7.5, 2, 14.5, 9, 17, 5, 19, 24, 8.5, 11.5, 13.5, 10, 18]
```

We could, of course, sort `times` and then apply `bsearch`, but sorting is expensive, having a time-complexity of O(n*ln(n)). If we wished to repeat the operation for multiple target values (e.g., `11`, `12`...), without changing `times`, the overhead of sorting `times` once may well be justified, but if we wished to perform the operation for only a single target value (such as `11`), it would be more efficient to simply perform a linear search:

```
times.min_by { |n| n >= 11 ? (n-11) : Float::INFINITY }
  #=> 11.5
```

`Float::INFINITY` is returned if `times.max < 11`.

See [Enumerable#min_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by).

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Range.html) and [`===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D):

> Returns `true` if obj is between begin and end of range, `false` otherwise (same as `cover?`).

```
(1..5) === 0 # => false
(1..5) === 1 # => true
(1..5) === 5 # => true
(1..5) === 6 # => false
```

If you want the range to be exclusive, you *can* use `...`:

```
(1...5) === 0 # => false
(1...5) === 1 # => true
(1...5) === 5 # => false
(1...5) === 6 # => false
```

But I don't recommend using `...` though. It's harder to spot when debugging and fools people who don't understand how it works which can introduce bugs.

> Ranges may be constructed using the *s..e* and *s...e* literals, or with ::new. Ranges constructed using `..` run from the beginning to the end inclusively. Those created using `...` exclude the end value.

It's better to use 4 (or the previous value) instead, which accomplishes the same thing:

```
(1..4) === 0 # => false
(1..4) === 1 # => true
(1..4) === 5 # => false
(1..4) === 6 # => false
```

Back to your question:

```
times = [2, 5, 7.5, 8.5, 9, 10, 11.5, 13.5, 14.5, 17, 18, 19, 24]
times.select { |i| (11 .. 11.5) === i } # => [11.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find first number greater than given number assuming the array is sorted,

```rb
times.find {  |time | time > given_time }
```

If array is not sorted, sort it first

```rb
times.sort.find {  |time | time > given_time }
```